# ASP.NET textbox right align-Cursor not displaying

Tags: asp.net

I have a normal textbox in a asp.net application.
Textbox's text align is 'right'  but i can not see cursor..
Once i added any numbers(Values) then it comes to visible..
Any suggestion..?

Answer (score 2):

```
.foo
{
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}

<asp:TextBox CssClass="foo" ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="right"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in your css file add a class like that

```
.right
{
    text-align: right;
    cursor: text;
}
```